# Zodiac Module on Polygon

Tags: gnosis-safe

we created a Gnosis Safe on Polygon and is trying to install the Zodiac (Safesnap) Module there. However, we are unable to 'install' it properly. Our safe is V1.3.0. While the transaction went through, the contract creation process threw out a single line of code rather than the series of files that we created with the rinkeby testnet.
Does anyone have experience doing the same and run into similar errors with this combination?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT #1 - to Richard

Thanks for your response thus far.

We also tried the UI in the beginning to install but when we went to the Zodiac sub-app it did not recognize the new module in the modules pane. We then went to try to enable the module 'manually' using the Transaction Builder but are hitting snags when we were trying to find out which mastercopy to be used in the tx. With regards to Richard's comment we will review the modules being set up (we actually removed all modules and then reinstalled again) and get back to everyone.

Comment: Would it be possible to share the Safe address or a transaction hash?

Comment: Also did you use the cli commands or the Safe app?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your Safe in the Safe web interface there are a couple transaction created via the Zodiac Safe App. All of them look ok.

Let's take an example: [image]

The first of the 2 transaction deploys the module. This is a minimal proxy that points to `0x72d453a685c27580acDFcF495830EB16B7E165f8` (the Reality module on Polygon and Mainnet).

The second transaction enabled this module.

So you are in the `Review` step of the [setup guide](https://gnosis.github.io/zodiac/docs/tutorial-module-reality/review-module).

Currently there is also another module enabled on the Safe (`matic:0x60573B8DcE539aE5bF9aD7932310668997ef0428`). This is not a module, but the oracle used by the RealityModule. I would recommend to remove that one again.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The UI does not show the module. Our other test safe on Rinkeby worked perfect. We need to add the module for our snapshot